# How to set which datasource will be affected by next and previous on form?

Tags: axapta

I have a form with two datasources (DS1,DS2). I set the datasource property on design to DS1. Until some trigger happen the previous and next are calling methods of DS1. Then I enable FormStringControl with datasource set to DS2 and the previous and next start calling methods of DS2. I need to ensure the metods will be called on DS1 everytime.

Is there some way how to reset focus back to the DS1?

Comment: I created some jumps to make sure if the next() is called on wrong datasource I make it call next on the right one etc. But it is not the nicest solution I ever made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, link type `Delayed` always behaves this way. In case there cannot be more than 1 record in DS2 linked to a record in DS1 (Cardinality = ZeroOne) you can try setting the link type to `OuterJoin` - it should help. It depends on what kind of data it is and how it is represented in the form.

Answer (score 0):

I think setting property 'DataSource' of 'Design' with the right DS will make the job.

Comment: I try this. When I switch some stringedit from disable to enable it switch datasource the next and previous are linked to.